# LBP Operator in FaceRecognizer in OpenCV

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

I am working on LBP Histogram of some image matrices using OpenCV and C++ and I need to calculate LBP(1,8) and LBP(2,16) of theses matrices. Latest version of OpenCV has direct support for calculating LBP FaceRecognizer with default LBP(1,8) operator and I can calculate LBP(2,16) by setting values while instantiating the object.

My question is that which matrix stores the LBP codes of given input matrix? Going deep in the implementation, I came to know that **predict(InputArray _src)** function first calls **elbp(src, _radius, _neighbors)** and then **spatial_histogram(/*params*/)** to calculate the histogram. But which matrix in these functions stores LBP codes??

Basically, what do these 2 functions (**elbp() and spatial_histogram()**) actually calculate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you look at the [training](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp#L820) and the [prediction](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/contrib/src/facerec.cpp#L842) step, you'll see, that the workflow for both is like the following:

- collect the lbp features for the whole image (elbp)
- split the lbp-image into nxn patches, collect a histogram for each patch, and concat them to 1 single   large histogram (spatial_histogram)

---

sidenote: i have some doubts on the usefulness of a 16-neighbour operator. you'll need 64k histogram bins per patch, and if your img is only 100x100, and 8x8 patches, you only have 144 pixels per patch/histogram. that will be a *very* sparse one. and your featurespace will explode! - less might be more here !

good luck, and happy hacking !

Comment: For an image of dims 100x100 having 8x8 patches, i think no. of patches would be 144 with 64 pixels/patch. And yes, when I generated the histograms of matrices after spatial_histogram() function, they were very sparse. Hardly some of the bars can be seen. My images are of dims 92x112. Any solution for that? I think in OpenCV, no. of bins used are 256 only for all cases.